# I imported money into etherscan but it didn’t show my real balance

Tags: remix, transactions, ether, metamask, etherscan

I’m devastated. I poured over a thousand dollars into eth and decided to invest it in a contract bot.  After I moved my money into the bot, it shows that I have successfully transacted the money (0.24666eth)into the bot in etherscan and I can see my money entering the wallet, however, the total balance of my wallet is still zero. Guys please help… it’s over 15 hours since I imported my money into etherscan. I can neither withdraw it from my bot or do anything about it… I’ve lost all my savings in seconds… I can’t afford this loss…

https://etherscan.io/address/0xe436d5c42445af92280ffac4af04b0da258e28db

Please help me out…

Comment: As per the [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd6555fc96eabc82b71e8fbe85acbe3191df3318bf55c01e946eb1933829a0931) flow, from the [contract bot](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe436d5c42445af92280ffac4af04b0da258e28db), the eth were transferred to this [address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xde0034bea9ea42fd502bd31d33025fd2ba8f2471), which in-turn [transferred](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2c307b60bf9dafe41bba1896b15014b62385fdebec6471e3722a4ce8ec1105bd) the eth to this [address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1b6ee1ddae1aecb01e151c21a11fc1848d6c339d).

Comment: Probably you deployed a scam contract after watching a YT video.